# Cassandra start error

Tags: cassandra

```
[root@localhost sri]# sudo sh ~/cassandra/bin/cassandra
```

Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.

If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option.

Comment: What do you want ? what kind of help you need

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 2):

Running C* with root permissions in not recommended in production environments.
Instead create a user account `cassandra` by executing `adduser cassandra`.
Then change the permissions of install directory, data, log, config directories of C* to `cassandra:cassandra` by executing `chown -R cassandra:cassandra`. After, run C* by executing `sudo -u cassandra $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with  sudo sh cassandra -R

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).